# Use (insert into ... returning id) as a value - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, insert

I *think* this is yet another twist on an old query, I've searched for a solution w/o success.

I have a table of, say, two values:

```
create table source (
a varchar(10) not null unique,
b varchar(10) not null
);
```

It's got 100000s of values.

I want to use them to initialise two linked tables, known to be empty (i.e this is not an upsert problem):

```
create table t1 (
id serial primary key,
x varchar(10) unique
);

create table t2 (
y varchar(10),
xp int not null references t1(id)
);
```

The following is conceptually what I want, but it's not allowed:

```
insert into t2(y,xp) select b,(insert into t1(x) values (a) returning id) from source;
```

Ideally I'd like to avoid looping over the source table more than once.

The best solution I've found that works is to define a *function* to insert into t1, giving

```
insert into t2(y,xp) select b,t1_ins(a) from source;
```

Somewhat surprisingly, defining the obvious view and an ON INSERT rule fails:

```
create view t2plus (
/* from t2 */
y,
/* from t1 */
x
)
as select y, x
from t2, t1 where t1.id=t2.xp;

create rule t2p_insert as on insert
to t2plus do instead
( INSERT INTO t1(X) VALUES (NEW.x);
INSERT INTO t2(y,xp) VALUES (NEW.y,currval('t1_id_seq')) returning xp;
);
```

This gives the obscure but explicit error:
  multi-statement DO INSTEAD rules are not supported for data-modifying statements in WITH!!!
(my big source array is actually a CTE)
when invoked as follows:

```
with source as (.....),
nextTab as (insert into t2plus(y,x) select x,y from source where y is not null),
...
```

So, is a function the only way?

Comment: Where do the mentioned rules come into play? Can you post the code for them as well? and the "view" you are talking about? Because you *can* achieve what you want with a data-modifying CTE.

Comment: Do note that the record in t1 can either be an existing row or a freshly inserted one. So the FK from t2 should refer to either the inserted or the existing tuple. So you need two table entries for t1 : one for the inserts the other for the existing tuples; glued together by UNION + (NOT) EXISTS (or maybe LEFT JOIN + COALESCE; not sure)

Comment: joop -- my bad, I failed to add that a is unique in source, so it's always an insert into t1

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name -- I've filled in the example with the view and ON INSERT rule

Comment: If a is unique in the source, then a is a candidate key. -->> `xp` in t2 is also a candidate key (since it is unique) could be a primary key (since it is NOT NULL) BTW: is the view called t1plus or t2plus ? Just asking ... NOTE: **please don't post pseudocode**

Answer (score 0):

```
create table source (
        a varchar(10) not null,
        b varchar(10) not null
        );

create table t1 (
        id serial primary key,
        x varchar(10) unique
        );

create table t2 (
        y varchar(10),
        xp int not null references t1(id)
        );

INSERT INTO source(a,b) VALUES
          ( 'a1' ,'b1' ) , ( 'a1' ,'b2' )
        , ( 'a2' ,'b1' ) , ( 'a2' ,'b2' )
        ;

WITH ins AS (
        INSERT INTO t1 (x)
        SELECT DISTINCT s.a
        FROM source s
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM t1 nx
                WHERE nx.x = s.a
                )
        RETURNING t1.id, t1.x
        )
, sel AS (
        select t1.id, t1.x
        FROM t1
        WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM source ex
                WHERE ex.a = t1.x
                )
        )
, two AS (
        SELECT ins.id, ins.x FROM ins
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sel.id, sel.x FROM sel
        )
INSERT INTO t2 (xp, y)
SELECT b.id, s.b
FROM source s
JOIN two b ON b.x = s.a
        ;

SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;

SELECT t1.id, t1.x
        , t2.y
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.xp = t1.id
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in practice source is very large, and I'd like to avoid scanning it twice

Comment: This is a general solution: if the tables are initially empty you can omit the select part and the union. BTW: In the past I have done stuff like this using rewrite rules. (deprecated, I know)

Comment: joop -- Please edit your solution to reflect that t1, t2 are empty going in and a is unique in source, so I can see how you are avoiding two passes in that case.

Comment: I just posted the complete code for the general case.And gave exlicit instructions for stripping it down for the simple case. The rest is left as an exercise to the reader ...

Comment: There are 7 selects in your solution, not sure which one(s) you mean can be removed, sorry.